# Convert uiwebview to pdf and emailing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have a Uiwebview which shows local htmls.I've done to convert html to pdf and can read on desktop.But when I attached pdf file to mail,It sent successfully but sometimes those pdfs can not be read in ipad or iphone?who has any suggestions to help me?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: if you can read these on a pc with adobe then the files should be OK - if not there is a problem in the file. Also even though there are iPhone/iPad pdf readers - I experience many cases where they cannot read all PDF files

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response.I don't know if having any ways which  converts to "safe" pdf or check it before sending mail.I mean It always can read by Ipad?

Comment: No I don't mean that you can check it before you send it - this will be very hard. I just think, that following my advice, you will find out, if the problem is with the generated PDF file in general or with some non-Apple compatible feature conversion.

Comment: I've solved it.it caused by my silly mistake.I forgot to add the tail of pdf file so Ipad can not realize.somehow it is not smart in this case.Anyway, Thanks so much.

Comment: it may be useful to other people if you say *how you solved* this problem, Stephen.